# Sklearn MLP Feature Selection

Tags: scikit-learn, neural-network, classification, feature-selection

Recursive Feature Elimination with Cross Validation (RFEVC) does not work on the Multi Layer Perceptron estimator (along with several other classifiers).

I wish to use a feature selection across many classifiers that performs cross validation to verify its feature selection.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Note:  The alternative is to use one feature selection method for some classifiers, and a different feature selection method for others, but this is not very elegant.

Comment: Is this still true?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure. :/

Answer (score 3):

There is a feature selection independent of the model choice for structured data, it is called **Permutation Importance**. It is well explained [here](https://explained.ai/rf-importance/index.html) and elsewhere.
You should have a look at it. It is [currently being implemented in sklearn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/13146).

There is no current implementation for MLP, but one could be easily done with something like this (from the article):

```
def permutation_importances(rf, X_train, y_train, metric): 
    baseline = metric(rf, X_train, y_train)
    imp = []
    for col in X_train.columns:
        save = X_train[col].copy()
        X_train[col] = np.random.permutation(X_train[col])
        m = metric(rf, X_train, y_train)
        X_train[col] = save
        imp.append(baseline - m)
    return np.array(imp)
```

Note that here the training set is used for computing the feature importances, but you could choose to use the test set, as discussed [here](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/feature-importance.html).