# Feature selection in sklearn neural network

Tags: python, scikit-learn, mlp

Let's consider data:

```
import pandas as pd 

x_train = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 2]])
y_train = pd.DataFrame([1, 0, 1])
```

I want to check which variables are important in this primitive example when using neural network. So if we do:

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE

# Define neural network classifier

clf = MLPClassifier(max_iter = 1000,
                activation = 'logistic', 
                    random_state = 1)
# Select two most important variables
selector = RFE(clf, n_features_to_select=2, step=1).fit(x_train, y_train)
# Extract names of the most important variables
print(selector.get_feature_names_out())
```

However, I get the error:

```
ValueError: when importance_getter=='auto', the underlying estimator MLPClassifier should
have coef_ or feature_importances_ attribute. Either pass a fitted estimator to feature
selector or call fit before calling transform.
```

Could you please help me solving it?

Comment: It's exactly as the error says: MLPClassifier does not have coef_ (used by shallow models such as linear/logistic regression or Naive Bayes) or feature_importances_ (present in models such as decision trees and random forests). There isn't a most agreed-upon way to do feature selection in multilayer NNs, so sklearn doesn't implement it.

Comment: @desertnaut, this problem has a solution, can you open this?

Comment: @I'mahdi OK, since you say so

Comment: Indeed RFE cannot be used with MLP; see [Sklearn MLP Feature Selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41082835/sklearn-mlp-feature-selection)

Comment: @I'mahdi can you now *please* vote to close this as a duplicate yourself? I cannot redo it :(